# What datatype of SQL column to use for images and documents

Tags: c#, database, database-design, database-schema

What data type should be use for files such as:

doc, xls, jpg, png, dwg

With a size of between 0.1 to 10 MB what should be?

```
Varbinary (x)
Varbinary (max)
Image
```

Comment: If you are 100% sure you want to store that kind of stuff in the db use [varbinary(max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx). Don't use [image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) as it is deprecated from sqlserver 2012 onwards

Comment: I googled or you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg316765(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: For storing files, VARBINARY or FILESTREAM is best. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450432/sql-server-how-to-store-binary-data-e-g-word-file

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `varbinary(max)` for every file

In `SQL 2012` you might use `image` but it wouldn't be supported in next generations of SQL Servers.

`Varbinary (x)` will be useful for avoiding storing larger files than desired.

Comment: Do **NOT** use `Image` anymore! It's deprecated and will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` for **ALL** binary data. Same applies to `TEXT` and `NTEXT` - do **not** use those anymore. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)